# Reverting multiple checkins in perforce

Tags: perforce

I have made several checkins using perforce.  I have no realized that all of them are unnecessary.  I would like to revert all the changes for the last *x* revisions in the working directory, update the version number, and check in.

I am familiar with Mercurial.  The way that I would it for that would be:

```
$ hg revert -r last_good_changeset .
$ edit version-number.txt
$ hg ci
```

Is there a way to do something similar in perforce?

Answer (score 2):

In Perforce, a `revert` refers to restoring a file to the state it was in before it was checked out.  What you're looking to do is back out a submitted changelist.  [This Perforce KB article](http://kb.perforce.com/article/14/backing-out-submitted-changelists) has a few methods to do what you're trying to do, depending on your particular circumstance.

For example, if you have revisions #1 - #6 of a particular file, and you want to roll back to revision #3, you'd do this:

```
p4 sync myfilename#3
p4 edit myfilename
p4 sync myfilename
```

You're telling Perforce to get revision #3 from the depot, check it out for edit, then try to sync it back up to #head (the latest version in the depot).  Since the file is checked out from an earlier revision, Perforce schedules a resolve so you need to tell it what you want to do with the file: accept the version in the depot, accept your local changes, or try to merge the two.  You'll want to tell Perforce to accept the local version (or in Perforce parlance "yours"):

```
p4 resolve -ay myfilename
```

Now that it's resolved, you can submit it with:

```
p4 submit
```

If you have a series of files you want to do this with (for example, you've edited a bunch of files in a given directory and have checked them all in together several times, and you want to back out all of those), you can use changelist syntax as well.  For example, if you want to roll everything back in a given directory to changelist 123, you can do this:

```
p4 sync //depot/some/path/*@123
p4 edit //depot/some/path/*
p4 sync //depot/some/path/*
p4 resolve -ay //depot/some/path/*
p4 submit
```

This will work for any revision modifier (see `p4 help revisions` for alternate methods of specifying the version you want).

Comment: `revert` means the same thing in Mercurial.  However, you can revert individual (or sets) of files to any particular revision.  Unless I am missing something, it doesn't seem as simple in Perforce.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mercurial, but based on my brief Googling, it sounds like yes - you're right that it's not quite as simple, syntactically at least.  I've edited my answer to be a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The rollback function is specifically designed to do this.  It goes back to a certain date/time or change list # and reverts all changes in the window you give it.

Simply right click on the file in question (P4V obviously) and select rollback.  It will bring up this box.  Not sure how to execute from command line...Ill see if I can figure it out and add that info.

[image]